# How do I find doctors who work in the same specialty but live in different cities using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join

The goal is to select all doctors who work in the same specialty, but come from different cities. I tried the two code options below but they didn't produce the desired results.

[Image of doctors table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiW30.jpg)

```
select * from doctors s
    join doctors c
    on s.specialty = c.specialty 
    and c.doctor_id <> s.doctor_id
where s.city <> c.city
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.first_name, 
    d1.specialty,
    d1.city AS city1,
    d2.city AS city2
FROM doctors d1`your text`
JOIN doctors d2 ON d1.specialty = d2.specialty 
AND d1.doctor_id <> d2.doctor_id
WHERE d1.city <> d2.city;`your text`
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It ran *completely* out of support over **4 years** ago.

Comment: Looks like some normalization would help you out here. At the very least I would slice Specialty and Hospital into their own tables.

Comment: For the question at hand what about your code doesn't work? Not sure why you some of your logic in the join predicate and others in the where clause. But with the sample data your code should return what you state you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.first_name, 
    d1.specialty,
    d1.city AS city1,
    d2.city AS city2
FROM doctors d1
JOIN doctors d2 ON d1.doctor_id <> d2.doctor_id  
WHERE d1.city <> d2.city and d1.specialty = d2.specialty
```

Additionally, your join condition should only be id's not equality. And your where conditions should be cities and specialties.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean you want all doctors matching that condition, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM doctors AS d
WHERE city != ANY
    (SELECT city
    FROM doctors AS e
    WHERE d.specialty = e.specialty);
```

Or do you really want all *pairs* of doctors satisfying such a condition:

```
SELECT d.doctor_id, d.first_name, d.last_name, d.city,
       e.doctor_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.city
FROM doctors AS d, doctors AS e
WHERE d.specialty = e.specialty
AND d.city != e.city;
```

I am making the assumption that doctor_id is unique in your table and therefore that each doctor belongs to one city only. If that's incorrect then please tell us what is/are the key(s) of your table. Better still, post the CREATE TABLE statement. Hopefully one of these queries is close to what you need.